# Laravel 4 Sub-views: style.css not loading

Tags: css, laravel-4, subview

I'm still new to laravel. The problem I'm facing is that in my main view, I'm loading a sub-view using

```
@include('subview.blade.php')
```

This sub-view generates a list with a specific content passed to it through the controller.
My problem is that style.css is not being loaded. I can't use the inline style cause I have some hover and other selectors.

I tried writing

```
{{HTML::style('css/style.css') }}
```

but still not working

Does anybody have any idea how to work this out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `{{HTML::style('css/style.css') }}` in the main template or in the subview?

Comment: It is in the template of course, but since it's not loaded, I tried to write it in the subview as well, but it didn't work either

Comment: are you getting any errors in browser console?

Comment: No, there's no errors at all.

Comment: If you inspect the HTML using browser dev tools, is the `<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">` tag being generated?

Comment: Also not working. This is what I found strange. I mean there should be some way to load a css file without a full html document.

Comment: What's the answer to @MichaelColeman's question? Is there a `<link>` tag in your page source? Also, are you generating a full HTML document with `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>` tags? I'm not an expert on the HTML specs, but it would not surprise me that a browser would not load a CSS file without a full HTML document.

Comment: Are you sure that your Template is used? :-)

Comment: can you give the directory structure of your application